/dev/ttyUSB0 is not associated with the USB port on the Rasberry PI board
I'm trying to connect a tablet to send commands to code running on a Raspberry PI, which, in turn, would control the opening and closing of a valve. The tablet and the board recognize the USB connection, and I can even put it in tethering mode. However, when I access the terminal and type the command ls /dev/tty* to see which /dev/tty this connection is associated with, nothing different appears compared to when the USB cable is disconnected. You can even create /dev/ttyUSB0 with the command sudo mknod /dev/ttyUSB0 c 4 74, but it is created as virtual and is not related to the physical USB port. How can I resolve this?

You have something plugged in to the Pi.  You have something plugged in to the tablet.  There is a wire between them.  What are these things?  There are thousands of different USB devices.

I will answer my own question, because two professors at the university where I study explained to me that /dev/ttyUSB0 from the tablet's USB port to the Raspberry PI's USB port does not exist. I would have to adapt it via the GPIO pins. Other ways would be to create a TCP/IP connection or replace the Raspberry PI with the Arduino. I preferred to create the TCP/IP connection. It worked.
